# How to run boost asio resolver service on more threads?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am using boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver in an SNMPV2 implementation to determine wheather a host is reachable or not.

```
using Resolver = boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver;
Resolver resolver(ioService);
Resolver::query query(connectOptions.getHost(),
        connectOptions.getPort());
Resolver::iterator endpointIterator;
BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, Severity::debug) << "Waiting for async resolve";
endpointIterator = resolver.async_resolve(query, yield);
BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, Severity::debug) << "Async resolve done";
if (endpointIterator == Resolver::iterator{}) { // unreachable host
    using namespace boost::system;
    throw system_error{error_code{SnmpWrapperError::BadHostname}};
}
```

I have one test case where I test what is happening when a non existent hostname and an exitent hostname is queried paralell:

```
2013-09-16 10:45:28.687001: [DEBUG   ] 0x88baf8 SnmpConnection: connect                                                                                              
2013-09-16 10:45:28.687396: [DEBUG   ] 0x88baf8 SnmpConnection: host: non_existent_host_name_                                                                        
2013-09-16 10:45:28.687434: [DEBUG   ] 0x88baf8 SnmpConnection: port: 1611                                                                                           
2013-09-16 10:45:28.687456: [DEBUG   ] 0x88baf8 SnmpConnection: Waiting for async resolve                                                                            
2013-09-16 10:45:28.687675: [DEBUG   ] 0x88c608 SnmpConnection: connect                                                                                              
2013-09-16 10:45:28.687853: [DEBUG   ] 0x88c608 SnmpConnection: host: 127.0.0.1                                                                                      
2013-09-16 10:45:28.687883: [DEBUG   ] 0x88c608 SnmpConnection: port: 1611                                                                                           
2013-09-16 10:45:28.687904: [DEBUG   ] 0x88c608 SnmpConnection: Waiting for async resolve                                                                            
2013-09-16 10:45:31.113527: [ERROR   ] 0x88baf8 SnmpConnection: Host not found (authoritative)                                                                       
2013-09-16 10:45:31.113708: [DEBUG   ] 0x88c608 SnmpConnection: Async resolve done                                                                                   
2013-09-16 10:45:31.113738: [DEBUG   ] 0x88c608 SnmpConnection: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:1611
...
```

From the logs it can be seen that the object with the reachable address is blocked until the other one's resolve is finished with the error (3 seconds).
My assumption is that Asio resolver service uses one thread, so one query towards one unreachable host might block the processing of upcoming resolve requests.

Workaround would be to run the resolver service on more threads, is that possible? Or would it be possible to have a resolver service which works on sockets like the udp service does (instead of using ::getaddrinfo)?

Comment: t should be possible, just remember to have one `io_service` instance per thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need are two `io_service ioService`, because each one is run by a thread. By that I mean that you block the normal execution of a thread by calling `io_service::run`.

I think that the code itself is correct.

Comment: The answer is OK, and it helped me a lot, so I accept this. But i don't agree on the because part. The reason is rather this: Each io_service instance has it's own resolver service instance with it's running resolver thread. So I needed to define two io_service instances just because of that. The thing that I need to have two threads in my client code is the consequence of having two io_service instances.

Comment: @Gabor Marton The `io_service` takes over control of the resolving, and you can't execute two `io_service::run` in one single thread, as they are blocking. So I don't really understand what you mean. Maybe we are having communication issues while meaning the same?

Comment: I don't think we mean the same. I think if I have two io_service instances and two thread objects running their io_service::run() method, than there are two additional threads which is running the resolver service internal thread. So I have at least 4 threads. If I would have a timer io object as well, initialized with one of the io_service, then I would have one more additional thread, as the timer service is also having its own running thread per io_service instance.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you meant that the resolve is happening in the io_service::run, but I think it is handled by resolver_service_base::work_thread_ object.

Answer (score 10):

As noted in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/implementation.html), Boost.Asio will create an an additional thread per `io_service` to emulate asynchronous host resolution on the first call to `resolver::async_resolve()`.

Creating multiple `io_service` objects will allow for concurrent host resolution only when initiating asynchronous resolution operations on `resolver`s associated with different `io_service`s.  For example, the following code will not perform concurrent host resolution, as both resolvers use the same service:

```
boost::asio::io_service service1;
boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver resolver1(service1); // using service1
boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver resolver2(service1); // using service1
resolver1.async_resolve(...); 
resolver2.async_resolve(...);
```

On the other hand, the following will perform concurrent host resolution, as each resolver is using a different service:

```cpp
boost::asio::io_service service1;
boost::asio::io_service service2;
boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver resolver1(service1); // using service1
boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver resolver2(service2); // using service2
resolver1.async_resolve(...); 
resolver2.async_resolve(...);
```

Assuming a `resolver` per `io_service`, to obtain concurrency, it becomes the applications responsibility to dispatch resolution operations to different resolvers.  A simple work distribution strategy, such as round-robin, may suffice.

On the other hand, one can delegate this responsibility to an `io_service`, allowing it to distribute work that will emulate asynchronous host resolution in a similar manner to what Boost.Asio does internally.  The synchronous [`resolver::resolve()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/resolve.html) member function performs work in the calling thread.  Thus, an application could create an `io_service` that is serviced by a thread pool.  When asynchronous host resolution needs to occur, a job is posted into the `io_service` that will create create a `resolver` and perform synchronous resolution, invoking the user handler with the results.  Below is a complete basic example where a `resolver` class emulates asynchronous host resolution with a thread pool:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

/// @brief Type used to emulate asynchronous host resolution with a 
///        dedicated thread pool.
class resolver
{
public:
  resolver(const std::size_t pool_size)
    : work_(boost::ref(io_service_))
  {
    // Create pool.
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < pool_size; ++i)
      threads_.create_thread(
        boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_));
  }

  ~resolver()
  {
    work_ = boost::none;
    threads_.join_all();
  }

  template <typename QueryOrEndpoint, typename Handler>
  void async_resolve(QueryOrEndpoint query, Handler handler)
  {
    io_service_.post(boost::bind(
        &resolver::do_async_resolve<QueryOrEndpoint, Handler>, this,
        query, handler));
  }

private:
  /// @brief Resolve address and invoke continuation handler.
  template <typename QueryOrEndpoint, typename Handler>
  void do_async_resolve(const QueryOrEndpoint& query, Handler handler)
  {
    typedef typename QueryOrEndpoint::protocol_type protocol_type;
    typedef typename protocol_type::resolver        resolver_type;

    // Resolve synchronously, as synchronous resolution will perform work
    // in the calling thread.  Thus, it will not use Boost.Asio's internal
    // thread that is used for asynchronous resolution.
    boost::system::error_code error;
    resolver_type resolver(io_service_);
    typename resolver_type::iterator result = resolver.resolve(query, error);

    // Invoke user handler.
    handler(error, result);
  }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
  boost::optional<boost::asio::io_service::work> work_;
  boost::thread_group threads_;
};

template <typename ProtocolType>
void handle_resolve(
    const boost::system::error_code& error,
    typename ProtocolType::resolver::iterator iterator)
{
  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << "handle_resolve:\n"
            "  " << error.message() << "\n";
  if (!error)
    stream << "  " << iterator->endpoint() << "\n";

  std::cout << stream.str();
  std::cout.flush();
}

int main()
{
  // Resolver will emulate asynchronous host resolution with a pool of 5
  // threads.
  resolver resolver(5);

  namespace ip = boost::asio::ip;
  resolver.async_resolve( 
      ip::udp::resolver::query("localhost", "12345"),
      &handle_resolve<ip::udp>);
  resolver.async_resolve(
      ip::tcp::resolver::query("www.google.com", "80"),
      &handle_resolve<ip::tcp>);
  resolver.async_resolve(
      ip::udp::resolver::query("www.stackoverflow.com", "80"),
      &handle_resolve<ip::udp>);
  resolver.async_resolve(
      ip::icmp::resolver::query("some.other.address", "54321"),
      &handle_resolve<ip::icmp>);
}
```

And annotated output:

```
handle_resolve:
  Success
  127.0.0.1:12345   // localhost
handle_resolve:
  Service not found // bogus
handle_resolve:
  Success
  173.194.77.147:80 // google
handle_resolve:
  Success
  198.252.206.16:80 // stackoverflow
```