# Socket hostname lookup timeout: how to implement it?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, timeout, gethostbyname

I write portable Windows/Linux application that uses sockets. I use `gethostbyname` function to perform DNS lookups.
However, I don't see how to set `gethostbyname` timeout and secure my application against hanging during name lookup.
Of course, it is possible to run `gethostbyname` on another thread, and that what I do. However, it is solution for trivial applications only.
My application uses 1000-3000 connections in parallel. In such situation the question is: what to do with timeouted threads? I don't see good solution. We can "forget" them, however, we are at risk that our program threads count will grow up to infinity on bad networks. We can terminate them, but the idea looks terrible. From my experience, Windows can crash after thousands of threads termination, and I don't know how Linux will behave in such conditions.
Also, thread creation needs many resources; it is not good idea to create 3000 threads just to run `gethostbyname` function and exit.
So, separate thread doesn't look like good idea for really complex application. Another alternative is to write own DNS client of course, however, it also doesn't look good.
Is there any "official" way on Windows and Linux (or better portable way) to get host address with custom timeout?

Comment: IIRC, some Windows and Windows Server versions do support asynchronous lookups, with timeouts, via the overlapped I/O mechansim, (GetAddrInfoEx). but this is hardly portable.  You could implement a fixed-size threadpool, (64?), to run the blocking queries and a delta-queue of 'DNSrequest' objects, run by one more thread, to implement your timeouts. You could implement that with POSIX semaphores and a sprinkling of other synchro objects.

Comment: You can use some third-party library for resolving or write your own implementation.

Comment: @Martin James GetAddrInfoEx is sockets 2, which is not portable and even worse, it is problematic to complile togeather with static library that uses sockets 1.1 like libcurl, openssl. Probably portable solution doesn't exist...

Comment: @GoodGuySoft - I'm fairly sure that you could implement such a system with POSIX threads and semaphores etc.  You should check out a lib or two before attempting to roll-your-own.  I will say, though, that continually creating, terminating and destroying a thread for each query is a really bad design for multiple reasons, some of which you already appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: don't use `gethostbyname()`, it's obsolete. Use `getaddrinfo()` instead.

What you want is asynchronous name resolution. It's a common requirement, but unfortunately there is no "standard" way, how to do it. Here my hints for finding the best solution for you:

1. Don't implement a DNS client. Name resolution is more than just DNS. Think of mDNS, hosts files and so on. Use a system function like `getaddrinfo()` that abstracts the different name resolution mechanisms for you.
2. Some systems offer asynchronous versions of the resolution functions, like glibc offers `getaddrinfo_a()`.
3. There are asynchronous resolution libraries, that wrap around the synchronous system resolver functions. At first [libasyncns](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/libasyncns/) comes to my mind.
4. Boost.Asio supports to use the resolver with a thread pool. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824746/how-to-run-boost-asio-resolver-service-on-more-threads).

Answer (score 1):

The most portable solution is indeed to use a separate thread for name resolution. This is also documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms741522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Non portable solutions exist that perform asynchronous name looksups.

Linux glibc 2.2.3+: [getaddrinfo_a](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo_a.3.html)

Windows: [WSAAsyncGetHostByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms741522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) IPv4 only :(

There are asynchronous DNS libraries out there: [TADNS](http://adns.sourceforge.net/) for example looks easy enough.